# Doubt on delta function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

So, I was solving a problem on quantum mechanics from a [problem set](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/919e31974c4feb023ce3532b64870f37_MIT8_04S13_ps2.pdf) (Problem 4) provided by MIT OCW.

I wasn't able to solve it on my own, so I looked at the [solution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/b5df068bbb4f0747ecc5e079da574e40_MIT8_04S13_ps2_sol.pdf).

I am having a doubt where $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i(k-q)x}dx$$ has been replaced by $$2\pi \delta (k-q)$$

Here's a snapshot from the solution:

[image]

I want to know how the exponential function was replaced by the delta function?

Comment: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.4985938

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i(k-q)x}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} cos((k-q)x)dx + i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} sin((k-q)x)dx$

Comment: @JohnRennie How to proceed next?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker It might!! But I am still new to the delta notation, so I can't understand much of it.

Comment: Strictly speaking $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} cos(ax)dx$ isn't defined, but $\int_{0}^{2\pi} cos(ax)dx = 0$ unless $a=0$

Comment: The integral you ask about is a symbolic notation. If you want to understand the math behind it, you might want to look into tempered distributions.